# Which server GGTS used for grails project deploy?

Tags: grails, jboss, vmware-server, ggts

> GGTS having VMWare vFabric TcServer. But I want to deploy my project
>   on JBoss.

I'm able to add new JBoss.x AS  and JBoss.x Enterprise Servers in GGTS but meanwhile if I try to deploy my application on Jboss I have an error alert message "**there are no resources that can be added or removed from the server**".

Same application I can deploy on default "VMWare vFabric TcServer" Server.

Comment: You have to add Jboss instance.
Try Window > Preferences > Server > Runtimes Environments.  Then, add the Jboss instance.

Comment: Thanks, I did and able to add JBoss, but while deploying facing same error message.

Comment: Is this because of WAR and EAR. I haven't yet created any WAR & EAR using Maven or Ant build. So is it mandatory??